# Не запускаются тесты через консоль maven+testNG

Tags: maven, selenium, testng

Использую IDEA+Maven+Selenium+testNG. Запуск тестов через Run внутри проекта происходит успешно. Через консоль командой **mvn clean test** - нет
Выводит следующие:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building 1 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ 1 ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\a\IdeaProjects\untitled\target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ 1 ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ 1 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1251, i.e. b
uild is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\a\IdeaProjects\untitled\targ
et\classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ 1
---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (Cp1251 actually) to copy filtered resources,
i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\a\IdeaProjects\unti
tled\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ 1 ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding Cp1251, i.e. b
uild is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to C:\Users\a\IdeaProjects\untitled\targ
et\test-classes
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.7:test (default-test) @ 1 ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\a\IdeaProjects\untitled\targ
et\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running TestSuite
There are no tests to run.

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.008 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-10-06T15:04:24+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 28M/341M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

как заставить работать через консоль правильно? чтобы выводил результаты тестирования?

Answer (score 1):

В pom.xml указан путь к testng xml?

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                        <suiteXmlFile>operator.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```